# Sending document information by PHP header OR HTML meta http-equiv?

Tags: php, html, http, http-headers

For sending HTML document information such as `content-encoding`, `charset`, `date`, `last-modified`, etc we can equally use PHP header `header()` OR HTML meta http-equiv `<meta http-equiv=... />`. Which is practically better? Can anyone elaborate the pros and cons of both methods?

I wonder if each of them has a better performance for specific application (e.g. one is better for defining `charset` and the other for `content-encoding`?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use real HTTP headers

- HTTP headers take priority over `<meta http-equiv`
- HTTP headers can be used by any HTTP client (instead of just those which parse HTML)
- HTTP headers can be used by clients that make a HEAD request
- Only a limited subset of HTTP headers are supported (by browsers) in `<meta http-equiv`

There is an argument to be made for including the charset information via a meta element as well (since that will be preserved if the document is saved and the copy is then accessed from the filesystem instead of over HTTP).

Answer (score 1):

The php "header()" function only sets the HTTP header: [header function on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) this is quiet useful if you want to attach a pdf document or something like that.

In your case I would use the ordinary html meta tags.

Answer (score 1):

Compromising with PHP headers is advantageous if using variables and CSS in correlation with each other, or if you are for some reason unable to modify .htaccess to allow custom content types like vector components and such.

HTTP and PHP headers are arguably one in the same, do the same thing.  One does not have significant utility over the other.